# sql return 0 if it is null w/ SELECT * COUNT, SQL queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please give me any advise.

I need to print out include '0'.

For example, I want to do like below, which include value 'd' and '0' but my real queries only print out just until third line (c, 3)

```
des   num   
---------
 a     1   
 b     2     
 c     3     
 d     0
```

Here is my code

```
SELECT des, COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM table 
WHERE color = 'Red' AND day = 17 
GROUP BY des
```

I so appreciate any advise

Comment: Try using SUM instead of COUNT and put your WHERE conditions inside of SUM. I am not sure about sqlite syntax. Mysql version: `SELECT des, SUM(IF(color='Red' and day=17, 1, 0)) AS num FROM table GROUP BY des`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause in your SQL statement limits the number of rows to be grouped to the ones having `color='Red' and day=17`. 
Among the rows returned to be grouped there isn't any row with `des='d'` and this is why you get this result.  
The below statement gets all the rows that your statement gets plus the ones that are excluded by `color='Red' and day=17`:

```
SELECT des, COUNT(*) AS num FROM table 
WHERE color='Red' and day=17 GROUP BY des
union
SELECT DISTINCT des, 0 AS num FROM table 
WHERE des NOT IN (SELECT des FROM table WHERE color='Red' and day=17)
```

Answer (score 0):

use ‘coalesce ‘ ... im pretty sure there is a lot of example out there.. 
 try this

```
  select coalesce(des, 0) as num
```

Comment: I dont know why but this one is not work for me. but thank you for answering my question !

Answer (score 0):

Simply use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT des,
       SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' AND day = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num 
FROM table 
GROUP BY des;
```

This is probably the simplest method to achieve what you want.